# Import table with images from google docs to google sheets

Tags: image, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to copy a table that contains images from Google Docs to Google sheets, I have tried the traditional method (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V) doesn't work, it just copies the texts from the table into the sheet but not the images.

You can however manually insert images in sheets by going to **Insert -> Images**, but the number of images to copy is large (around 650) so it will take a long time to manually do so.

I also tried messing with the xml structure of the doc and sheet (copying the table.xml file to the sheets) doesn't work because schema is different.

For context, images -
[image]

This is my table in google docs

I want this table to look something like this in google sheets -

[image]

Either in the cell or over the cell is fine.

But when using normal copy paste (Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V) it gets pasted like this -

[image]

since the number of images is >600 manually importing is a huge task.

Is there a better more easy way to tackle this problem ?

Comment: In your input Document, there is only one table including only one image in one Google Document? Or, there is a table including only one image in a Google Document, and there are the 650 tables in one Google Document? And, in your output Spreadsheet, how do you put the 650 images? In your question, only one image is put. But unfortunately I cannot understand your actual goal. I apologize for this. And, which do you want to achieve your goal by manual operation or a script?

Comment: @Tanaike   My google doc is a combination of tables and images I want to simply migrate the tables to excel as it is.


I my output, the image is added by going yo Insert -> Image -> Add over cell

I added one image as an example for what the issue is. My end goal is to completly copy the tables in my google doc to google sheets along with images inside the table

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `My google doc is a combination of tables and images I want to simply migrate the tables to excel as it is.`, in this case, there are 650 tables in one Google Document and each table has the image at row 1 and column 2. Is my understanding correct? And, I cannot still understand your goal. In your goal, when 2nd image is put to the Spreadsheet, what result do you want to achieve? Do you want to put 650 images to the 1st tab?

Comment: And, which do you want to achieve your goal by manual operation or a script? If you want to use a script, what language do you want to use?

Comment: @Tanaike my end goal is a script that can automate this. Your assumption is correct, although I have come up with a makeshift solution to do this so I will be closing this question.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post is as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike definitely, i will post an answer along with the script, if I am able to make it